# Finding general equation of surfaces orthogonal to a given family of surfaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find general equation of the surfaces orthogonal to the family of spheres given by $x^2+y^2+z^2=cz$
Please provide the process as I am struggling to identify the process

Comment: You should find the gradient vector which will be orthogonal to the family of given surfaces. Then the normal vector of any surface orthogonal to the given surfaces will also be orthogonal to the gradient vector. So their dot product will be zero.

Comment: The surfaces belong to the family defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2=xF(y/x)$ with $F(t)$ any differentiable function.